# Django Request.query_parmas issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

Below is the url that i am going to get, i am able to retrieve the specific data with the patientName and patientNRIC. However, how should I make to be variables, using params? like I would like to pass in to values to the function but achieved the same information instead of hard coded. Thank you for your help.

test.py

```
import requests


def get_patient():
    # patientName= {'patientName': patientName}
    # patientNRIC = {'patientNRIC': patientNRIC}
    p = {'patientName':'John','PatientNRIC':'S1111111A'}
    django_url = "https://4cfe2cdde986.ngrok.io/test/?patientName=John&patientNRIC=S1111111A"
    r = requests.get(django_url)
    r = r.json()
    print(r)


get_patient()
```

```
like so
```

Answer (score 0):

import requests

```
def get_patient(p):
    query_string = ''
    for query, value in p.items():
        query_string+=f'{query}={value}&'
    django_url = f'https://4cfe2cdde986.ngrok.io/test/?{query_string}'
    r = requests.get(django_url)
    r = r.json()
    print(r)

p = {'patientName':'John','patientNRIC':'S1111111A'}
get_patient(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) says

```
import requests


def get_patient():
    # patientName= {'patientName': patientName}
    # patientNRIC = {'patientNRIC': patientNRIC}
    p = {'patientName':'John','PatientNRIC':'S1111111A'}
    django_url = "https://4cfe2cdde986.ngrok.io/test/"
    r = requests.get(django_url, params=p)
    r = r.json()
    print(r)


get_patient()
```